# Why else statement is not executing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzoLk.png).click on the image to see the code.

Now look none of the perimeter is string but still the statement of if is executing.Why?

def calculatetiles(plot_width, plot_length, tile_width, tile_length):
#if type((plot_width) == str or plot_length == str or tile_width == str or tile_length == str:
if type((plot_width) == str or (plot_length) == str or (tile_width) == str or (tile_length) == str): #== str:
print("hello")
else:
print(None)
#elif plot_width == 0 or plot_length == 0 or tile_width == 0 or tile_length == 0:
#print("zero")
#else:
#aP = plot_width * plot_length
#aT = tile_width * tile_length
#calculatetiles = aT / aP
#calculatetiles = int(calculatetiles)
#print("The no of tiles is:", (calculatetiles))
calculatetiles(2, 3, 3, 3)

Comment: Where are `these parameters` ?

Comment: Looks like your variables are strings and `aP = plot_width * plot_length` will give you this error. You might want to check if you really have numbers. With `plot_width == str` you don't check if `plot_width` **has** the type `str`, you just check if `plot_width` **is** the type `str`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you're trying to do, however you might run into the problem of integer divison. Since you dont specify what the parameters are I will assume you have tought about this and do indeed try to divide two integers

```
def calculatetiles(plot_width, plot_length, tile_width, tile_length):
    if plot_width == str or plot_length == str or tile_width == str or tile_length == str:
        print("hello")
    elif plot_width == 0 or plot_length == 0 or tile_width == 0 or tile_length == 0:
        print("zero")
    else:
        aP = int(plot_width) * int(plot_length)
        aT = int(tile_width) * int(tile_length)
        calculatetiles = aT / aP
        calculatetiles = int(calculatetiles)
        print("The no of tiles is:", (calculatetiles))
```

**EDIT: since the question itself has been edited to a different Question...** 
First of all please provide code as formatted text, NOT as image, second in your edit, you do `if type(...):`
this will allways return true because the statement you put inside there is a boolean so type returns `boolean` which is not an empty value and therefore interpreted as `true` by the if statement. For your purpose, just remove the line. if you want to do it correctly you'd have to use `isinstance`

Comment: @Matthias if you read my answer, you'll see I mention the problem of integer division. If he has indeed not tought of that (which I actually think because he casts calculatetiles to int) I hope he will read up on it and realize to use float instead of int

Comment: @azro i'm passing these parimeters:
calculatetiles(2, 3, 3, "3")

Comment: @kay_g why arent you just passing (2,3,3,3) ? your program will work with these